# why async_read_until() stores delimiter as std::string internally?

Tags: networking, boost-asio

my question is about the theoretical explanation, because `asio` usually puts the user in charge of buffer lifetimes.
so why in the case of `async_read_until(string_view delim)` `asio` [copies](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/develop/include/boost/asio/impl/read_until.hpp#L1246) the delimiter allocating memory for this using `std::string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is for legacy support. The actual implementation defines the argument type as `BOOST_ASIO_STRING_VIEW_PARAM` which [in places where there exists no string_view will take `std::string const&`](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/develop/include/boost/asio/detail/string_view.hpp#L46).

That's step one. Here you could argue that it would be nicer if move-semantics were applied, but that would make it hard to get the required implicit conversions to std::string for types that are *compatible* but not actually `std::string&&`.

All in all, it's a compromise that is likely to go away in the future when older platforms/compilers are dropped.